# Spring enable a stand alone Java library

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

[New to Spring]

There is a service that is Spring enabled and does some stuff. When this service starts up, it loads the Spring Application context and everyone is happy.

Now, I need to create a library that will be used by the above mentioned service and I want to Springify this library package as well. But then, when/how does this library's application context get initialized? Am stumped!

I assume many people must have done this. What is the best practice?

I was thinking, may be a static block in the library's entry point interface is the right place to initialize the application context? (so, it gets init only once)

Is that the right approach? Is it even going to work or am missing I something? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can give as many applicatoin context xml files as you want, If you are using the library in a web application,

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
    classpath:context1.xml
    classpath:context2.xml
    ...
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

basically you need to provide the relative path `classpath:<relativepathofcontextfile>`.
If it is inside a jar file and your jar is in classpath the above one works.

If it is for standalone, You can use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private static final ApplicationContext ac= 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:context1.xml");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyIntf bean= (MyIntf) ac.getBean("myBean");
        bean.myMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, with using static block you are enforcing Spring context to load disregard the fact that it might be loaded yet in another classloader. So the good approach would be to provide some factory method to get business objects, which will track if the context is loaded yet and create one if necessary. Or use pre-existing context.

Also it might be a good idea to review Service Locator pattern and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider